# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'person' available

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

i'm trying to implement a simple crud application using spring so i want to insert data into the table "person" but it doesn't work  please can anyone help me and thank you 
 here is my config .xml file

[config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOo5Z.png)

Connect.java class: 
[Connect.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV84v.png)

Person.java :

[Person.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1swD3.png)

main :
[Test.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxBXp.png)

Comment: Please put code directly in the question instead of link to image.

Comment: ..and post exception in the question or please describe what exactly "doesn't work".